# Gears of War Chronology

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

With the release of Gears 1: Ultimate Edition coming down before Gears 4, I wanted to replay the games correctly. obviously, its chronology is 1, 2, 3 but where does judgement fit in to the game cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judgement is sort of parts of 2 and 3 from the alternate view of COG soldier, Baird.

Most of the game plays out through flashbacks, and theres the general assumption that the player has been through it's prequels.

It was originally released following 3, and follows it best, sequentially.

1 > 2 > 3 > Judgement.